# Why can a domestic wire transfer involve international intermediaries?

Tags: united-states, wire-transfer

I recently made a wire transfer from Fidelity to Wells Fargo.  I explicitly used their routing number rather than the SWIFT code.  From the posted transactions I see the fund comes from Citibank Europe.  And since they charged me $16 I'm sure sure this was an international wire.

How can an international bank get involved in a US domestic wire transfer?

Comment: What was the currency of accounts? What was the payment amount currency? What kind of account you have with Fidelity; i.e. savings/checking or Investment account.